# How to export all files and folders in resources folder in java

Tags: java, embedded-resource

How in java code do i copy everything from src/main/resources directory inside of the jar file into the same directory of the jar file?

Comment: What do you mean by "export"?

Comment: I want to copy the files that are inside of the jar to outside of the jar

Comment: jar is a zip file. You can export it and grab the resources from that.

Comment: I want to do it within the Plugin.java class, in Java code.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  Your application should not be copying those files just to read them.

Comment: @VGR I never did reply to you, but the files were config files and "default" images that the user can change. You shouldn't be telling people that they should not do something in code just because you assume that I'm extracting them just to read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i found from [org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/plugin/java/JavaPlugin.java#L239) and it seems to work

```
public void saveResource(String resourcePath, boolean replace) {
    if (resourcePath == null || resourcePath.equals("")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("ResourcePath cannot be null or empty");
    }

    resourcePath = resourcePath.replace('\\', '/');
    InputStream in = getResource(resourcePath);
    if (in == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The embedded resource '" + resourcePath + "' cannot be found");
    }

    File outFile = new File(dataFolder, resourcePath);
    int lastIndex = resourcePath.lastIndexOf('/');
    File outDir = new File(dataFolder, resourcePath.substring(0, lastIndex >= 0 ? lastIndex : 0));

    if (!outDir.exists()) {
        outDir.mkdirs();
    }

    try {
        if (!outFile.exists() || replace) {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
        } else {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Could not save " + outFile.getName() + " to " + outFile + " because "
                    + outFile.getName() + " already exists.");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not save " + outFile.getName() + " to " + outFile, ex);
    }
}
```